# Please advice why the form is not redirecting to the url?

Tags: php

Please help with this php contact form. It works, however, I want to redirect the visitor to a different .html page instead of showing a thankyou message, but i do not want to lose the contact form info.  Thanks !

I am using very simple contact form:

```
<form method="POST" action="sendmail.php" class="form">
        <p class="yourName"> Submit Name:</p>
        <input name="text" class="name" placeholder="Name" name="name">
        <p class="yourEmail">Submit Email:</p>
        <input type="text" class="email" placeholder="Email" name="email">
        <p class="yourInquiry">Submit Inquiry:</p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="Button">    
    </form>






<?php
    $to = "xyz@hotmail.com";
    $subject = "Inquiry from ". $_POST['name'];
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    $html`enter code here` = "";
    foreach ($_POST as $name => $value) {
        $html .= "<strong>$name</strong><br>";
        $html .= "<p>$value</p><br>";
    }
    if (mail($to, $subject, $html,$headers)) {
        /* Success Message */   
    } else {
        /* Error message */
    }


    header('Location:about.html');

    } else {
    echo "You didnt enter anything";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

`header` and related functions (in particular `setcookie`) MUST appear before ANY content on the page. In this case, your form is sent before it.

You can either rearrange your code so that the form processing appears before the form, or start your code with `ob_start` to bypass the restriction (but this is only a good idea if you actually intend to pass a callback to the function)

Comment: Thanks every one . But I am a bit new to php . I just know css and a html. I have used the php form code from somewhere.What I meant to ask was how can i redirect the form to a different .html page on a website. But I dont want the email addresses to disappear once it is redirected.

Comment: you can add email & name to the forwarding URL:

   header('Location:/about.php?email='.urlencode($_POST['email']).'&'.name=urlencode($_POST['name']);


and in about.php print it out like this:

Thank you  <?=url_decode($_GET['name'])?> Your email was: <?=url_decode($_GET['email'])?>

Answer (score 0):

You must not output (or echo) anything before using function `header()`

Put all your logic on the top of your script and html markup on the bottom, so you would be able to perform  `header('Location:about.html');`

Answer (score 0):

First if you want to redirect using header location you can't show any message like Success Message or Error Message.

Second use header("Location:about.html");

Try it change the order of your code as show below

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["yourName"])){
    $to = "xyz@hotmail.com";
    $subject = "Inquiry from ". $_POST['name'];
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    $html`enter code here` = "";
    foreach ($_POST as $name => $value) {
        $html .= "<strong>$name</strong><br>";
        $html .= "<p>$value</p><br>";
    }
    if (mail($to, $subject, $html,$headers)) {
        /* Success Message */   
    } else {
        /* Error message */
    }


    header("Location:about.html");

    } else {
    echo "You didnt enter anything";
}
    ?>

<form method="POST" action="sendmail.php" class="form">
        <p class="yourName"> Submit Name:</p>
        <input name="text" class="name" placeholder="Name" name="name">
        <p class="yourEmail">Submit Email:</p>
        <input type="text" class="email" placeholder="Email" name="email">
        <p class="yourInquiry">Submit Inquiry:</p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="Button">    
    </form>
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot output anything before your header statement and you have to change your header() statement to:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/about.html');
```

Comment: Why would he need to change the header to an absolute form? Location works great with relative paths.

Comment: It is up to the client whether or not to accept relative path in the header location statement; therefore, I use absolute paths.  Reference http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Relative paths are part of the HTTP/1.1 specification and all major browsers support this. Thus you are just creating confusion by insisting that OP has to rewrite his code on this point.

Comment: @Andreas, whether "All major browsers" support this or not does not invalidate my statement nor the statement of PHPs own documentation on this point.